# An error occurred while running cordova build android

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic2

I want to check GPS is enabled or no in user device so for that I installed ionic 2 native diagnostic plugin and tried to build apk using

> ionic cordova build android

but getting below error while doing so, I have installed Google Support Repository in Android studio, I have attached the screenshot of the error, tried most possible ways published in stackoverflow but could not resolve the issue, please someone guide me achieving this. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: can you add the output of `cordova requirements` command? Also please post output as text and not image

Comment: @SurajRao apologies for late was stuck with other tasks.. So to check whether the GPS is enabled or no in user device I used Ionic native plugin called Diagnostic, the commands I executed are [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic/)

Answer (score 0):

Open Android SDK Manager and update android support repository to resolve the issue. Please refer this [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/141)